# PHP Как передать в функцию определённую переменную, когда их несколько?

Tags: php

есть функция `draw_submit(30, “OK”)`
которая на вход принимает `function draw_submit($width = -1, $text = “save”, $title = “”, $extra = “”, $class_name = “”)` 
я хочу на вход передать три параметра width, text и class_name `draw_submit(30, “OK”, “send_month”)`, но вместо class_name у меня параметр передается в title. Как передать сразу в class_name?

Comment: передать пропущенные параметры равными из значению по умолчанию. Если у вас пхп8+ то именованные аргументы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете пренебречь аргументами, которые имеют значения по умолчанию, но пренебречь их порядком -- не можете. Поэтому вам нужно передать что-то вместо аргументов, которых у вас нет. Обычно используется `NULL`:

```
draw_submit(30, "OK", NULL, NULL, "send_month");
```

Поскольку у вас начальные значения по умолчанию у пропущенных аргументов должны быть `""`, то их можете и передать:

```
draw_submit(30, "OK", "", "", "send_month");
```

UPD: обычно используется не `NULL`, а параметры по умолчанию.

Comment: обычно используется значение параметра по умолчанию, а не null.

Comment: @teran, да, мне просто чаще всего встречалась именно передача NULL на практике. А так да, вы правы. Сейчас подкорректирую ответ

Comment: спасибо, решение помогло

Answer (score 0):

Главное правило: перечислять вначале обязательные параметры, потом необязательные.

Если все необязателньные, то можно задуматься над несколькими вещами

1. А на сколько часто я передаю параметры и какие именно. Может быть выделить несколько методов, которые принимают разные параметры в зависимости от цели
2. А зачем вообще столько параметров в методе? Почему их так много? Может эти параметры связаны как-то в единый контекст и тогда надо создать какой-то класс со свойствами и пользоваться гидратором и дегидратором, чтобы эти свойства парсить и создавать объект, а **в метод просто передавать этот самый объект**. Т.е. будет всего лишь один параметр с типом `MyObj $obj`. Очень удобно
3. Возможно тут имеет место быть применение паттерна проектирования.
4. Ещё в *PHP8.0* появилась возможность указывать имена параметров. Можно воспользоваться ею

   ```
   function foo($a, $b = '', $c = '') {
       echo $a . '&' . $b . '&' . $c;
   }

   foo("hello", c: "bar");
   ```

Comment: 2. просто в массив упаковать, на край к `(object)` привести

Comment: @teran в теории можно, но класс более наглядный, особенно с phpDoc  и hints